# Error using netCDF4 num2date function

Tags: python, netcdf4

I am working with an nc file.The file has an array of dimensions time, number, latitude, longitude. I was trying to convert time from number to date via the `num2date` method.

```
time_unit = nc.variables["time"].getncattr('units') # first read the 'units' attributes from the variable time
print(time_unit)
time_cal = nc.variables["time"].getncattr('calendar') # read calendar type
local_time = nc.num2date(t, units=time_unit, calendar=time_cal) # convert time
print("Original time %s is now converted as %s" % (time[0], local_time[0]))
```

But i am facing the following error.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-124-d9912be48299> in <module>()
      2 print(time_unit)
      3 time_cal = nc.variables["time"].getncattr('calendar') # read 
calendar type
----> 4 local_time = nc.num2date(t, units=time_unit, calendar=time_cal) # 
convert time
      5 print("Original time %s is now converted as %s" % (time[0], 
local_time[0]))

netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__getattr__ 
(netCDF4\_netCDF4.c:20474)()

netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.getncattr 
(netCDF4\_netCDF4.c:19433)()

netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4._get_att (netCDF4\_netCDF4.c:4451()

AttributeError: NetCDF: Attribute not found
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

`nc`  is your open netCDF file but `num2date` is located in `netCDF4`:

```
>>> import netCDF4
>>> netCDF4.num2date
<function netCDF4._netCDF4.num2date>
```

Therefore, call it like this:

```
local_time = netCDF4.num2date(t, units=time_unit, calendar=time_cal)
```